# how to find a text and copy the text after?

Tags: search, text

I have a script that create a txt file with a lot of information. I want to check if there is a specific text in it, and copy what come after.
for example, this is the txt file:

```
blablablaWANTEDTEXT[TEXTTOCOPY]blablabla...
```

where I want to check if `WANTEDTEXT` is exist and if so, copy what come next in `[` and `]` aka `TEXTTOCOPY`.

thanks

Comment: well, I did "grep "WANTEDTEXT" input.txt > output.txt" but it also give me the text that I already know. I need just what come after, and I don't know how to do that... @GypsyCosmonaut

Comment: I mean, it did copy what come after but it also copy the text that I search for, and that I don't want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> echo blablablaWANTEDTEXT[TEXTTOCOPY]blablabla... | 
> awk -v searchtext=WANTEDTEXT '$0 ~ searchtext "\\[.*\\]" {
    strstart=index($0,searchtext "[")+length(searchtext)+1;
    tmpstr=substr($0,strstart); sub("].*$","",tmpstr); print tmpstr; } '

TEXTTOCOPY
```

Comment: Complicated, clumsy and without explanation, so the OP won't learn to help himself.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '....' | grep -oP 'WANTEDTEXT\[\K[^]]*'
```

Where you operate `grep` in the `Perl` mode, meaning, you can write Perl regexes in `grep` and the `-o` will print just the matching portion, instead of the whole line as is it's wont.

Note: Any thing to the left of `\K` will not show up in the output. It's a sort of a keeper flag (lookbehind but variable length) that instructs `grep` to use it in matching but NOT outputting.

---

### Result:

```
TEXTTOCOPY
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
greptext=$(echo blablablaWANTEDTEXT[TEXTTOCOPY]blablabla | grep "WANTEDTEXT")
if [[ -n $greptext ]]; then
  ftext=$(echo "blablablaWANTEDTEXT[TEXTTOCOPY]blablabla" | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1)
  echo $ftext
fi
```