# Find a text string in a file and output only the rest of the text that follows it?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pipe, stdout

I am finding a lot of posts on this forum that have to do with finding various values in a text file and outputting text surrounding it.  However, I don't seem to find any "stream oriented".

I want to find a particular string in a file, and output *only* the text that follows it until the end of the file is reached.  In other words, I want something that acts like a filter that ignores the text in a file until a specific string value is reached, and then from that point on outputs text to *stdout* until the end of the file.  I want to use *stdout* so I can pipe output to a file if I so chose.

Is there a Linux text utility that will help me do this and if so, how?  Or if I need to write a bash shell script to accomplish that, what are the general steps and command line utilities I would use to do this?

For example, given a sample file below:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

Suppose I wanted to output all the text after the "three" so the result would be:

```
four
five
```

NOTE: I did find this seemingly related post but as you can see it's a bit of a mess:

[how to find a text and copy the text after?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385311/how-to-find-a-text-and-copy-the-text-after)

Comment: Is "three" unique? What if are more than one ocurrences?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17908555/1331399)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 's;/^three$/{s=1}' file
```

or

```
awk 's;$0=="three"{s=1}' file
```

- `s;` will print the line if variable `s` is true, which is the case first time after the pattern/word has been found ...
- `/^three$/{s=1}` will set variable `s` to true (1) if pattern/word is found.

Answer (score 9):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 0,/three/d
```

Note that Linux is a kernel, it doesn't have utilities. GNU `sed` is the `sed` implementation commonly found on GNU/Linux systems like Debian GNU/Linux. GNU `sed` predates Linux and has been compiled to run on most Unix-like systems including most of those running Linux as their kernel. It is itself a Free, Libre and OpenSource re-implementation (with a few extensions including that `0` address) of the UNIX `sed` utility from the late 70s.

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX sed you can do as:

```
sed -ne '/three/!d;:a;n;p;ba' inp.file
```

Using Perl:

```
perl -lne 'print if 1 <(/three/...eof)' inp.file
```